# Laravel-Excel 3.1 csv import Date column not converting

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, laravel-excel

I was trying to import csv file using Laravel-Excel 3.1. In the csv file have a date column and it's format is 'dd/mm/yy', example - "24/07/20". I am using ToModel method. How can I save intu the database in format of "yyyy/mm/dd", exaple - "2020/07/24". My code is as followed.

```
class DeviceDataImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    private $counterNumber;

    public function __construct($counterNumber)
    {
        HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');
        $this->counter = $counterNumber;
    }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
       return new DeviceData([
            'counter_id'        => $this->counter,
            'date'              => $row['DATE'],
            'amount'            => $row['AMOUNT'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've approached a manual method as follows.

```
$year = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row['DATE'])->year;
$month = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row['DATE'])->month;
$day = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row['DATE'])->day;
```

And after that I had concat and reformat the date manually as per my project.

```
'date' => Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $day . '/' . $month . '/' . 20 . '' . $year),
```

I think it's not a very good solution, but will work for the next many years.

Thanks to all for contributing ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['DATE'])),
```

[Read more about strtotime function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: My csv is returning "24/07/20", your code is returning "1970-01-01"

Comment: whats the cell format of date field in your csv file?

Comment: When i'm seeing in cell it's showing "dd/mm/yy", when I'am clicking it's showing "dd/mm/yyyy". When i'm doing dd($row['DATE']); in import function it's showing "dd/mm/yy".

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create a date instance using Carbon, as thus you should have

```
DeviceData::create([
            'counter_id' => $this->counter,
            'date'  => Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $row['DATE']),
            'amount' => $row['AMOUNT']
           ]);
```

You might want to use validations incase the date is other wise but be sure it is of that format

Again I don't know if counter is what I am thinking but it can be gotten from the import see - https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html#keep-track-of-the-row-number

Hope this helps thanks

Comment: It's showing Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing. When I am doing ```dd(Carbon::createFromFormat('yyyy/mm/dd', '24/07/20'));``` it's result is same.

Comment: `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $row['DATE'])` is the correct syntax, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: It's saving "0024-07-20"

Comment: You need to parse the correct format, as per your question you mentioned this `yyyy/mm/dd` so it should work. Unless your date is not in that format.

Comment: You can use artisan tinker and play with the dates to see the correct format. Else look here to see yours - https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

Carbon's `createFromFormat()` requires you to define the **input** format.

In this case, the input format for 24/07/20 is `d/m/y`, not what is being used in the other answer.

See [PHP: DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for a listing of parameters.

```php
'date' => Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $row['DATE']),
```

If you do not want to save the model using a Carbon instance, you can format the date as a string. This is where you would define a specific output format.

```php
'date' => Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $row['DATE'])->format('Y/m/d'),
```